# can I combine electrical cords and their dimmeers?

Tags: electrical

I have three identical floor lamps grouped together.  Each came with its own cord and slide  dimmer on the cord.  I would like to combine the three cords and have them all run on the same in cord slide type dimmer.  Is this possible?

Comment: [dimmer extension cord](https://www.google.com/search?q=dimmer+extension+cord&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is no, not a good idea to do this.

First, splicing cords is a bad idea as they become fire hazards.  A splice drastically weakens the cord possibly allowing the conductors to separate which then will cause sparking.  The other, is the dimmer.  The manufacture of the lamp most likely used the cheapest dimmer possible to run the lamp.  Putting three lamps on one dimmer will most likely overload it.

I recommend looking for a new lamp that provides the lighting you need in a single package.